# Can't create Segue from UIScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I have a UIScrollView with my View, but I can't seem to create a seque push from this over to another controller.

I have successfully created a Seque from a UICollectionViewCell over to my destination controller but when I try and create one from the UIScrollView (in the StoryBoard) the blue connector will not see the destination controller as an option to create a segue too.

Any pointers would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

A push segue is only meant to be used with any type of button (ex. `UIButton`, `UIBarButtonItem`) or cell (`UITableViewCell`). Push segues are used to show another view controller over the current one. `UIScrollView` is only meant to scroll the content on the current view controller, just in case the content of the view controller exceed the screen size. I suggest you look at the Apple UIScrollView Class Reference page [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html) to get a better understanding of UIScrollView

Comment: Thanks, I had a feeling that was the case, I'll take a look at the reference page in full detail and take it from there...

Answer (score 0):

Push segues don't have to be connected from individual views like UIButtons or UITableViewCells. This is too limiting, because a button (for instance) can only connect to one segue. Try connecting them from the view controller itself, then you will be able to do as many as needed. I open the Document Outline, and drag from the View Controller at the top of the scene (the item having the yellow circle icon next to it) to the view controller on the Storyboard that I want to connect to.